# JavaScript beginner, help me fix things using Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am trying to become better with JavaScript and I have done a great job at breaking a page really badly :)))))

I am trying to use Firebug to debug, but it is a little confusing at first. Which of its tabs is used to debug JavaScript?  I see DOM and Script - which should it be?

My general problem is this page:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/add_spotted_trees.php?hike_id=108

I made a login for people:
login: test@comehike.com
password: password

What I was trying to do on that page is to get the "clear all" and "clear last" links to work correctly, but I just created a hit mess :)

What happens now is that markers are placed, but after "clear all" the markers aren't recognized and not put into the "rout_markers" id element.

Any clues on how I can get this resolved or at least heading in the right direction?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be watching the Console tab for errors and warnings. For instance, you have two I've seen:

On page load:

```
YUI is not defined
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/add_spotted_trees.php?hike_id=108
Line 256
```

After logging in and clicking Remove All Markers:

```
markers[array_length - 1] is undefined
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/add_spotted_trees.php?hike_id=108
Line 322
```

Also, instead of using `alert()` to test, you can use `console.log()`, which will print to the console. Just remember to remove these before going live.

In addition, you may want to check out some videos:

http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/javascript/15-essential-javascript-video-tutorials

And go through some tutorials:

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/category/firebug-tutorial/

**EDIT**

Following my comment, here is what I have done to combat the console.log() conundrum:

```
try{console.log();}catch(e){var console=new Object;console={log:function(){ininklklaskjdflk=0;}};};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what Jared says, using console.log() is a much more efficient way of debugging that alerting everything. However, if you leave this in and visit the page in a browser that doesn't have a console, it will crash. You can just remove the console.log() calls, or if you are worried about forgetting those, you can just use this little piece of code:

```
if(window.console && console.log) console.log("Log Something");
```

All that does is check a console exists before sending something to it. If the console doesn't exist, that if statement will evaluate to false, meaning console.log("Log Something") is never run. If you liked you could also write this like so:

```
if(window.console && console.log) {
    console.log("Log Something");
}
```

Both mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: If you use console.log exclusively (and not any or alot of the other functions), you can instead detect when they AREN'T available and create a dummy console.log(), which would essentially dump it into nowhere. This is much easier than adding that to every console.log call.

Comment: The best way would be to create your open wrapper function that would do it, or use one of the ones already out there such as http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/

Comment: Either way is much simpler than always using a cumbersome if statement, IMO. I hadn't heard of this particular solution; thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

The script pane lets you look at the source of all the javascript running on the page. And you can setup breakpoints and look at variables....

The Console Pane is probably the most useful.

You use it to see errors and console.log statements (from Jack Franklin's Post). You can also run javascript from a "command line" to test it on the page.